# Stripe API get invoices is empty but payment intents successful

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using NODE JS Stripe API (in test mode) to fetch a customers invoices as follows:

```
stripeInvoices = await stripe.invoices.list({
    customer: user.stripeCustomerId
})
// => Returns: { data: [] }
```

But it returns an empty list even though I can see transactions in the dashboard (See image below).
[image]

As a side node, I store the payment intents IDs in my own database during the payment process and can get the info that way but why is the invoice empty?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you actually using Invoices, or are you trying to list [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list)? Those are two different objects.

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference. I'm just trying to get all the transactions from the customer (and was hoping that Stripe had an automatic "receipt" page that I can share with the customer instead of coding my own).

Comment: Your answer fixed it. Thanks @taintedzodiac